# Segmentation fault using MeasureTextEx()

Tags: c++, raylib

I ran into a problem while using Measuretext().

My goal is to ru

```
#include <raylib.h>

int main()
{
    Font font=GetFontDefault();
    const char *text="Hello world!";
    float fontSize=10.f;
    float spacing=10.f;

    Vector2 textSize;
    
    textSize=MeasureTextEx(font, text, fontSize, spacing);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried modifying the sourcecode of MeasureText() but upon removing part of the code, it also returned segmentation fault

```
#include <raylib.h>

int main()
{
    Font font=GetFontDefault();
    const char *text="Hello world!";
    float fontSize=10.f;
    float spacing=10.f;

    Vector2 vec;

    // Check if default font has been loaded
    if (GetFontDefault().texture.id != 0) //<- Upon removing this, it also returns segmentation fauls
    {
        vec = MeasureTextEx(font, text, (float)fontSize, (float)spacing);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to InitWindow() before using MeasureTextEx()